# Is there a way to fix the memory leak in 5.0.1

Tags: 5.0-lollipop, samsung-galaxy-s-4

I'm using a Samsung GT i9500 running 5.0.1 stock firmware. The RAM gets full after a few days and device gets extremely laggy.

Is there a way to fix this by modifying some system files? If yes, what are the steps? Even theoretical answers will do.

Comment: Is rebooting every "few days" an issue?

Comment: Yes it's very inconvenient.

Comment: I guess that @MatthewRead was being sarcastic. End user devices aren't made for being kept up and running for several days in a row. That's a job for servers.

Comment: By few days I mean two days. Why are people so mean?

Comment: Not being sarcastic.  I reboot my phone every couple days myself if not more often, and don't consider it "very inconvenient" as it's just a press of a button when I go to bed.

Comment: I use Tasker on my rooted phone to reboot it every couple of days. at a time I don't need it.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have the Facebook app installed? I've noticed that Samsung phones get very laggy when the app is installed. Uninstalling the app immediately makes the phone run quicker.